# @patch decorator cannot set Provider

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I tried patching a provider class by decorating a test method with `@patch`:

```
class TestMyUnit(unittest.TestCase):
...
@patch(provider.Provider,autospec=True)
def test_init(self, mock_provider):
    pass
```

However, when I run the test, I get the error:

```
*@patch(provider.Provider)*  
*File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mock.py", line 1518, in patch*  
*getter, attribute = \_get\_target(target)*  
*File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mock.py", line 1367, in \_get\_target*  
*target, attribute = target.rsplit('.', 1)*  
*AttributeError: class Provider has no attribute 'rsplit'*  
*ERROR: Module: test\_my\_unit could not be imported (file: C:\dev\src\test\_my\_unit.py).*
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use a string instead of the class.

```
@patch('provider.Provider', autospec=True)
def test_init(self, mock_provider):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Te actual solution for your answer is that you have to use patch.object if you are using the imported class.

These two are the same

```
@patch.object(provider.Provider, autospec=True)
def test_init(self, mock_provider):
    pass

@patch('provider.Provider', autospec=True)
def test_init(self, mock_provider):
    pass
```

Which one to choose?

If you already have the imported class, you can use it,  it is more readable. If you have to import it to patch it, then use a string